# One time custom cron schedule in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I want to run a cron just once at a custom date & time entered by the user in a form. What is the best way to do this?

I found that a custom cron can be scheduled  in laravel like this

```
->cron(‘* * * * * *’);
```

> Run the task on a custom Cron schedule.

But I could not find the time format what the * mean.

Or much simpler, can it be done like this by adding the date and time.

```
->at('28/04/2020 13:00');
```

How can this be done?

Comment: A lot of cron maker can help you: https://crontab.guru/. For example, * means all value. So '* * * * * *' will run every minutes. 

Other site : http://www.cronmaker.com

Comment: Minute hour day month day. Thats 5 values. Laravel specifies 6 * values in the cron

Comment: The 6th element could be the day : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: What if I want to fire it only once. Can I append ->once() to it?

Answer (score 4):

you can easily do that with when() method

```php
    $schedule->command('command')->when(function (){
        return Carbon::create(2020,4,28,13)->isPast();
    });
```

Comment: Can I use the when() method to append after call() or is it used specifically only for commands?

Comment: also can use with call() method

Answer (score 4):

@the_hasanov answer is the closest one but it's not complete:

Using his method will run the closure every minute after the date you want!

There is -at least- two methods to avoid this.

### 1. Using a "already_runned" status

The first one is to store the "already run" status of the schedule somewhere: database or file and use this kind of schedule:

```php
// Using a scheduled closure here to be explicit
// Setting is a generic model to store configuration data.
//   it could be replaced by Redis or other key/value storage
$schedule->call(function() {
    // Run here the wanted logic
    Setting::create(['name' => 'cron_already_runned', 'value' => true]); // Store the already_runned status
})->when(function (){
    $already_runned = Setting::firstWhere('name', 'cron_already_runned');

    return
        optional($already_runned)->value
        &&
        Carbon::create(2020,4,28,13)->isPast();
});
```

### 2. Using two "time-condition" which could be true only once

The second one is to use a double "time-condition" which could be true only once:

```php
$schedule->command('command')->when(function (){
    return
        Carbon::create(2021,4,28,13)->isPast()
        &&
        Carbon::create(2021,4,28,14)->isFuture();
});
```

*Using this method is not 100% safe as it could fail if the server is down when the conditions are met*

Answer (score 1):

Laravel documentation has in detail description on that in here [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling)

You can add your scheduling logic in a given file

> App\Console\Kernel

Currently, laravel have the kind of functionality that exactly match your requirement but it provide a `->monthlyOn(23, '13:00');` via which you can achieve your requirement, **It Run the task every month on the 23th at 13:00**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {

        })->->monthlyOn(23, '13:00');
    }
```

The above code runs the task every month on the 23th at 13:00 hours server time.

For your purpose you can change cron scheduling as given below

```
00 13 28 APR Fri *

1st * Minute
2nd * Hour
3rd * Day of the Month
4th * Month of the Year
5th * Day of the Week
6th * Year
```

Comment: I have seen dailyAt But the first word in my question is one time. Can you tell how to do that?

Comment: Nah. I need it just once, not every month.